# Query result to xlsx and send mail in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xlsx, openrowset

There is a procedure in which an Excel file is created, the result of the selection is saved in it. This file is attached to the letter and sent by mail. But the problem is that the file is created and sent empty. Manually everything works, but not together.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_sendMail]
    @SID INT,
    @EMAIL VARCHAR(512),
    @CUR INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @MAILID INT,
        @TABLEHTML VARCHAR(MAX),
        @CMD SYSNAME,
        @FILENAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PID INT,
        @DATE_START DATE,
        @DATE_END DATE

    SELECT
        @PID = PATIENTS_ID,
        @DATE_START = DATE_START,
        @DATE_END = DATE_END
    FROM 
        TABLE 
    WHERE 
        ID = @SID

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'sp_configure ''show advanced options'', 1; reconfigure; '
    EXEC ('RECONFIGURE')
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'', 1; reconfigure;'
    EXEC ('RECONFIGURE')

    SET @FILENAME =  'D:\' + CAST(@SID AS VARCHAR) + '_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 104), '.', '') + '_' + CAST(@CUR AS VARCHAR) + '.xlsx'
    SET @CMD = 'copy D:\Example.xlsx ' + @FILENAME  

    EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @CMD;

    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', 
  ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @FILENAME + ';HDR=YES'',
  ''SELECT DATE, CODE, LABEL, CNT, CU, SCO, DISCOUNT FROM [Sheet1$]'')
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, ORDER.DATE, 104) DATE,
        EMPLOYEE.CODE CODE,
        EMPLOYEE.LABEL LABEL,
        CAST(ORDER.CNT AS INT) CNT,
        CAST(ORDER.PRICE AS MONEY) CU,
        CAST(ORDER.PRICE_TO_PAY AS MONEY) SCO,
        CAST(ORDER.DISCOUNT AS INT) DISCOUNT
    FROM 
        ORDER
    JOIN 
        EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE._ID = ORDER._ID 
    WHERE
        (CONVERT(DATE, ORDER.DATE) >= CONVERT(DATE, @DATE_START) 
        AND CONVERT(DATE, ORDER.DATE) <= CONVERT(DATE, @DATE_END))
        AND (ORDER.ID in (@PID))
    ORDER BY ORDER.DATE'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
         @SQL,
         N'@DATE_START DATE, @DATE_END DATE, @PATID INT',
         @DATE_START = @DATE_START,
         @DATE_END = @DATE_END,
         @PID = @PID

    SET @TABLEHTML =
    N'<H1>Hello!</H1>' +
    N'<span>num: </span>' + CAST(@SID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) +
    N'<span>, email: </span>' + CAST(@EMAIL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) +
    N'<span> sent! </span>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'site.com',
  @recipients = 'admin@site.com',
  @subject = 'subj',
  @body = @tableHTML,
  @body_format = 'HTML',
  @file_attachments = @FILENAME,
  @mailitem_id = @mailid output 


IF (@MAILID > 0 AND @@ERROR = 0)
  UPDATE TABLE SET [SIGN] = 1, [SENT] = GETDATE(), SENDER = @CUR WHERE ID = @SID


EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'sp_configure ''show advanced options'', 1; reconfigure; '
EXEC ('RECONFIGURE')
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'', 0; reconfigure;'
EXEC ('RECONFIGURE')

END
```

Comment: Just speculating here. But could it be SQL server hasn't finished writing to spreadsheet and it's sending the email without waiting? Is there perhaps a way it could be transactionalised. Per here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213696

Comment: What do you mean? How do it with waiting?

Comment: Sometimes code executes asychronously  not linearly top to bottom. So the code falls through and does not block and execute line by line. You see it a lot with things like web service calls to return a payload - JavaScript doesn't block - it has something called the event loop.

Comment: But, how to make the code run synchronously in order?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: OK thanks. But I think the problem is not related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **JGFMK** was right!
If execute this code, then openrowset will be done:

```
if( 1 = 0)
begin
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
  'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\file;HDR=YES',
  'SELECT DATE, CODE, LABEL, CNT, CU, SCO, DISCOUNT FROM [Sheet1$]')
    SELECT..
end
```

How to make it work by condition ?